# python __main__ and __init__ proper usage

Tags: python, initialization, program-entry-point

Since I'm rather new to python this particular aspect of language still opaque for me.

So, assume that my project contains many files with code that does stuff and two "service" files: `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`

In `__init__.py` there is only:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import package.__main__
    __main__.main()
```

And in `__main__.py` as follows:

```
import package # ok
import package2 # ok

def main():
    package.myfunc1() # can't find reference to myfunc1
    package2.myfunc2() # can't find reference to myfunc2
```

So my question is: why both packages are visible while functions inside are not? I've read some source code from google and still can't spot the difference between it and my code. I'm using `Python 3.5.1`

I assume, that code in `__init__` will launch `__main__` and `__main__` will launch the rest of my functions.

**UPD**

Well, my apologies if I confused someone with my code. 
The idea that stand behind `__init__.py` is that file was created by IDE when the first package was added so I decided to fill it with [code](https://github.com/Sveder/pyweek_18_game/blob/100dd6197962508a78172c0945b9c914040bda7b/byte/byte/__init__.py) found on first github entry(my fault, I though it can be re-used by copy-paste).

Strictly speaking I just need python construction, that equivalent this C code:

```
header.h
void func1(){...} //in code1.c
void func2(){...} //in code2.c
#include "header.h"
int main() //in main.c 
{
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

And the following code

```
import package
import package2 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    package.myfunc1() 
    package2.myfunc2()
```

has exactly same issue that stated above, so the matter is not in `__init__.py`

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing, don't put code in `__init__.py`, you'll only confuse yourself unecessarily and gain nothing. (If you do know what you are doing, pity the next reader and don't put code in `__init__.py` without compelling reason and comments that justify it.)

Comment: `__init__.py` has a defined place in package structure.  I don't think `__main__.py` does.  When a script is run, `__main__` is the name of the base namespace, hence the `if __name__ ...` idiom.  The two uses of `__main__` are not the same.

Comment: @hpaulj: In Python 3.1+, if a directory or zipfile has a `__main__.py` file, you can run it by specifying just the path to the directory/zipfile.

Comment: Yes, that's what I discovered in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I made:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
```

with the 2 files being:

```
# __init__.py
import __main__
print('in init')
print('init name',__name__)
```

and

```
# __main__.py
print('main name',__name__)
print('in main')    
if __name__=='__main__':
    print('in main main block')
```

If I run `__main__` directly:

```
1538:~/mypy$ python foo/__main__.py
('main name', '__main__')
in main
in main main block
```

It does same thing if I invoke the directory.  It does not import `__init__.py`.

```
1541:~/mypy$ python foo
('main name', '__main__')
in main
in main main block
```

But from a shell, it loads both files

```
1542:~/mypy$ python
....
>>> import foo
('main name', 'foo.__main__')
in main
in init
('init name', 'foo')
```

But it does not use the `if __name__` block of `__main__` - the name isn't right, it's now `foo.__main__`.

---

relevant docs

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#interface-options

> Execute the Python code contained in script, which must be a filesystem path (absolute or relative) referring to either a Python file, a directory containing a `__main__.py` file, or a zipfile containing a `__main__.py` file.

[`https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html)

> This module represents the (otherwise anonymous) scope in which the interpreter’s main program executes — commands read either from standard input, from a script file, or from an interactive prompt. It is this environment in which the idiomatic “conditional script” stanza causes a script to run:

---

I created another directory with an `__init__.py` but no main:

```
1558:~/mypy$ python foo1
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in 'foo1'
1558:~/mypy$ python
...
>>> import foo1
('in init', 'foo1')
>>>
```

`import` works, but I can't `run` the directory.

Comment: thanks for tips, it helped me to figure out several things to finally find the solution for my problem. Unfortunately, cant accept your answer as soon as there is no direct code that suits my purpose

Answer (score 2):

Well:

`__init__.py`
Is useful for `import` (all subdirectories are search for import)

And

`if __name__ == "__main__":`

is use to run a module itself. But this par of code would not be executed if imported in other script

Comment: The question is about the file `__main__.py`, not the module name `__main__`.

Comment: @chepner: no. In `__init__.py`, `if __name__ == "__main__":` is the first statement. And that's call `main` function in this module. But sure, some explanation may be added!

Answer (score 0):

So, as stated in question for such C code

```
header.h
void func1(){...} //in code1.c
void func2(){...} //in code2.c
#include "header.h"
int main() //in main.c 
{
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

there is some kind of python solution:

```
def func1() #  in function1.py in package Foopackage
def func2() #  in function2.py in package Foopackage
```

as follows `__main__.py`:

```
import Foopackage.function1 as f1
import Foopackage.function2 as f2


def main():
    f1.func1()
    f2.func2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

No `__init__.py` required. In my case assumed that all files are located in same directory.

Any corrections are welcome.